# JSFiddle not working in Safari 4.0.5 on windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, jsfiddle

This is the first time I've ever tried a JSFiddle in Safari.  Is there some goofy reason that JSFiddle wouldn't work right in Safari 4?  Someone did report that Safari 5 works fine.  So what am I missing here?

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#productSize").change(function(){
        var me = $(this);
        var avail = me.find("option:selected").html().split("-")[1].trim();

        $("#quantity option").each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        for(var i=1; i<= avail; i++) {
            $("#quantity").append("<option>"+i+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<label>Sizes
    <select name="item_options[product_size]" id="productSize">
        <option value="s">small - 10</option>
        <option value="m">medium - 1</option>
        <option value="l">large - 5</option>
        <option value="xl">extra large - 10</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label>Quantity
    <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
    </select>
</label>
```

JSFiddle demonstrating problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/hqLPp/)

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying this in all other browsers, finding different behavior in all of them.  This does exactly what it's supposed to in Firefox.  No problems.  IE doesn't seem to like how I'm calling trim() so I've changed the JSFiddle to accommodate that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#productSize").change(function(){
        var me = $(this);
        var myText = me.find("option:selected").text().split("-")[1];
        var avail = parseInt($.trim(myText), 10);

        $("#quantity option").remove();

        for(var i=1; i<= avail; i++) {
            $("#quantity").append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqLPp/8/) This has been tested and works in IE, FF, Chrome, but still I get nothing, the $(document).ready & the .change() don't even execute in Safari 4.

**UPDATE #2** 
Just to clarify even further, this Jquery code does not run in JSFiddle/safari 4.0.5.   I don't even get the alert so the .change() isn't running...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#productSize").change(function(){
        alert("Hello World");
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI - It works in Safari 5.1 on Windows 7

Comment: It doesn't do anything for me using Safari 4.  In fact I can't get any JSFiddles to work in Safari 4 unless its a really really simple alert("hello").

Comment: Thanks for the edit Matt but the problem isn't that the code doesn't work in Safari...Actually it does if I just load up a page.  What I'm after is why doesn't the same code work when I load it up in JSFiddle in Safari 4.0.5.

Comment: @brenjt are you using Safari 4.x?

Comment: @kasdega Ah, I am using 5.0, I must have updated my Safari and didn't realize. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that there is a limitation with JSFiddle and Safari 4.0.5.  I can't get even the simplest selectors to work and kick off a very simple binding.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/wryqn/) works in every browser I've tried (FF multiple versions, IE 7 & 8, Chrome 12.0.x, & Safari 5.1).  If anyone can explain why I'd love to hear it otherwise I'm just going to assume this is a bug in either Safari 4 or JSFiddle.  Either way I'm moving onto more current browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Try the jsFiddle JSLint button - it shows a couple of errors which I think are causing your display problems.

Comment: `$(this).remove();` - this is undefined.

Comment: I don't get any JSLint errors.  $(this).remove(); absolutely should exist.

Comment: I'm still getting errors with your updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hqLPp/8/ - the error is: "Error: Problem at line 9 character 17: this is undefined / Implied global: $ 1,2,3,5,7 / Unused variable: avail 2 "change" NOTE: I have replaced line breaks with forward slashes.

Comment: try the javascript from my update #2.  Basically remove any and all javascript code and when the drop down changes try and pop up an alert.  This is super simple stuff and Safari doesn't do it.  I'm wondering if this is a bug with JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#productSize").change(function(){
        var me = $(this);
        var avail = parseInt(me.find("option:selected").text().split("-")[1].trim());

        $("#quantity option").remove();

        for(var i=1; i<= avail; i++) {
            $("#quantity").append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Same result.  I get nothing when doing this in a JSFiddle in Safari 4.0.5.